# How do I get all the spans within the div in PHP?

Tags: php

im using `simple_html_dom.php` 
for example I'm using this code to get one span inside the div but I want to get the three spans that it has inside instead of writing one `foreach` for each span.

```
for(){
    foreach($html->find('span.street-address'$i) as $e){
          $list[$i] = $e->plaintext;
          echo $list[$i];
        }
}
```

another thing, the div that I want to get the information from the HTML file is

```
<div class="address adr">
    <span class="street-address">
        <span class="no_ds">...</span>
        <span class="postal-code">...</span>
        <span class="locality"></span>
    </span>
<div>
```

I want to get everything within the div class.
there is also a phone div that is diferent.

```
<div class="phone tel">
    <span class="no_ds"></span>
<div>
```

as you can see one span class "no_ds" is the same name as the other span class. Will that have any affect on my code? The space between "address adr" and "phone tel", how do I write that in the code? with a period?

Comment: no, as I have said before I'm using simple_html_dom.php so I load the HTML file with $html = file_get_html($url); then I look for the divs

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName is the answer here.

```
// gets all SPANs
    $spans = $dochtml->getElementsByTagName('span');

    // traverse the object with all SPANs
    foreach($spans as $span) {
      // gets, and outputs the ID and content of each DIV
      $id = $span->getAttribute('id');
      $cnt = $span->nodeValue;

      echo $id. ' - '. $cnt. '<br/>';
    }
```

Comment: The OP is using simple_html_dom library, which doesn't have `getElementsByTagName` or `getAttribute()` or `nodeValue` (which are DOMDocument methods/properties)

Comment: there are multiple other spans that I don't want the information from. That is why I only want those divs